# Datatables fixedHeader option doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables and having a problem with the fixedHeader option:
the header won't freeze like expected after adding the `fixedHeader: true` flag as documented [here](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
    Schedule Match
 | Upstream Commerce</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script/api_recs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script/site_filter.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.3/dt-1.10.12/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.3/dt-1.10.12/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.js"></script>



    <style type="text/css">
        tfoot {
            display: table-header-group;
        }

        html {
            width: 57.5%;
        }

        input:checked {
            height: 17px;
            width: 17px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <img id="loader" src="/static/img/loader_animation_large.gif" 
    style="
        width:36px; 
        height:36px; 
        display: none;
        position:absolute; 
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        margin-top:-18px;
        margin-left:-18px;"/>
    <p><a href="/accounts/logout/">Logout</a> | <a href="/accounts/profile/">Home</a></p>


    <table id='pm_table' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
        <thead>
        <tr>

                <th>Site id</th>

                <th>Site name</th>

                <th>Priority</th>

                <th>Schedule</th>

                <th>Last run time</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>

                <th>Site id</th>

                <th>Site name</th>

                <th>Priority</th>

                <th>Schedule</th>

                <th>Last run time</th>

        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>537</span></td>

                    <td><span>kobo_us</span></td>

                    <td><span>90</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>1970-01-13  20:38:31</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>553</span></td>

                    <td><span>kobo_uk</span></td>

                    <td><span>90</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>1970-02-08  13:55:33</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>562</span></td>

                    <td><span>kobo_au</span></td>

                    <td><span>80</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>1861</span></td>

                    <td><span>alliance_entertainment</span></td>

                    <td><span>55</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>1970-04-01  00:29:37</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>1845</span></td>

                    <td><span>ubs.com</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>611</span></td>

                    <td><span>officebrands</span></td>

                    <td><span>75</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>1970-03-19  03:51:06</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>512</span></td>

                    <td><span>cos.net.au</span></td>

                    <td><span>70</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>1853</span></td>

                    <td><span>debonix.fr</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>-104</span></td>

                    <td><span>bestonix</span></td>

                    <td><span>100</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>1813</span></td>

                    <td><span>destination_reward</span></td>

                    <td><span>30</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>1794</span></td>

                    <td><span>petco_new</span></td>

                    <td><span>10</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>1940</span></td>

                    <td><span>eventyrsport.dk</span></td>

                    <td><span>30</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>746</span></td>

                    <td><span>burketts</span></td>

                    <td><span>90</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>735</span></td>

                    <td><span>sigmapharmaceuticals</span></td>

                    <td><span>34</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>651</span></td>

                    <td><span>ulta_new</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>767</span></td>

                    <td><span>markertek.com</span></td>

                    <td><span>90</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>304</span></td>

                    <td><span>lakeland.co.uk</span></td>

                    <td><span>46</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>459</span></td>

                    <td><span>smythstoys.ie</span></td>

                    <td><span>5</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>453</span></td>

                    <td><span>smythstoys.com</span></td>

                    <td><span>5</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>1902</span></td>

                    <td><span>toysrus.uk</span></td>

                    <td><span>5</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>573</span></td>

                    <td><span>toysrus.es</span></td>

                    <td><span>10</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>209</span></td>

                    <td><span>rockbottomgolf.com</span></td>

                    <td><span>333</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2949</span></td>

                    <td><span>free_people</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2964</span></td>

                    <td><span>shopbop_ch</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2974</span></td>

                    <td><span>shopbop_sk</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>2016-11-07  14:36:27</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2975</span></td>

                    <td><span>shopbop_au</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2976</span></td>

                    <td><span>shopbop_hk</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2977</span></td>

                    <td><span>shopbop_tai</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2978</span></td>

                    <td><span>shopbop_uk</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2979</span></td>

                    <td><span>shopbop_jap</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>2980</span></td>

                    <td><span>shopbop_fr</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3019</span></td>

                    <td><span>zooroyal</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3050</span></td>

                    <td><span>hhgregg</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3121</span></td>

                    <td><span>gopro</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3199</span></td>

                    <td><span>groupon_uk_demo</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3206</span></td>

                    <td><span>groupon_fr_demo</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3215</span></td>

                    <td><span>partycity</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3294</span></td>

                    <td><span>silver_star</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3349</span></td>

                    <td><span>asos_uk</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3353</span></td>

                    <td><span>mango</span></td>

                    <td><span>333</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3372</span></td>

                    <td><span>netshoes</span></td>

                    <td><span>53</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>            <tr>

                    <td><span>3019</span></td>

                    <td><span>zooroyal</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3050</span></td>

                    <td><span>hhgregg</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3121</span></td>

                    <td><span>gopro</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>1</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3199</span></td>

                    <td><span>groupon_uk_demo</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3206</span></td>

                    <td><span>groupon_fr_demo</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3215</span></td>

                    <td><span>partycity</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3294</span></td>

                    <td><span>silver_star</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3349</span></td>

                    <td><span>asos_uk</span></td>

                    <td><span>50</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3353</span></td>

                    <td><span>mango</span></td>

                    <td><span>333</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><span>3372</span></td>

                    <td><span>netshoes</span></td>

                    <td><span>53</span></td>

                    <td><span>0</span></td>

                    <td><span>-</span></td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // DataTable
            var table = $('#pm_table').DataTable({
                dom: 'l Bfrtip',
                "aLengthMenu": [
                    [20, 50, 100, -1],
                    [20, 50, 100, "All"]],
                "buttons": [],
                "bFilter": false,

                paging:false,
                fixedHeader: true


            });
            // Apply the search
            table.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I checked the includes and the console does not show any error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you added necessary javascript files for fixedHeader.

Comment: yes, I double checked  I used the [download builder](https://www.datatables.net/download/) correctly.

Comment: @MaxSegal, I have the same problems, have you solved ??

Comment: yes, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you did not include css file for fixedHeader in your code. please include the link `https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.css` in head section of your page. It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by **removing** these lines from `<style>` section:

```
tfoot {
            display: table-header-group;
      }
```